# Collapsible sub categories for ReactSelect

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is it possible to make sub categories collapsible using ReactSelect?
Given the image below, can `plan` and `period group` be collapsible?
My select is defined like:

```
<ReactSelect<OptionType, IsMulti>
      classNamePrefix="react-select"
      tabSelectsValue={false}
      {...props}
      className={classnames('react-select-wrapper', props.className)}
      styles={getStyles<OptionType, IsMulti>(props.styles, props.isInvalid, props.isMulti)}
    />
```

Do I require an additional prop?

[image]